# google colab modifying file issue

Tags: google-colaboratory

The code is working in google colab, but still it doesn't modify files. Below is the code.

```
def normalise_zero_one(path):
"""Image normalisation. Normalises image to fit [0, 1] range."""
sitk_t1 = sitk.ReadImage(path)
t1 = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(sitk_t1)
image = np.array(t1, dtype=np.float32)

minimum = np.min(image)
maximum = np.max(image)

if maximum > minimum:
    ret = (image - minimum) / (maximum - minimum)
else:
    ret = image * 0.
return ret

for i in path2:
  t1_fn = os.path.join(t2_path, i)
  normalise_zero_one(t1_fn)
```

Still I don't know why the targeted files in 't1_path' do not change after running the code (resample_img) even without any errors.

Comment: you are not overwriting the original file, you just return the ndarray ```ret``` in your function and not even using that in the script body. OpenCV has direct scaling functions you may want to use them, such as ```image.convertTo(tempImage, CV_32FC3, 1.f/255);``` and then save this output using ```imwrite```

Comment: BTW regular RGB uint images can have values in [0, 255]. In your code, 0 and 255 do not correspond 0 and 1, instead correspond to min and max of that particular image, therefore your scaling may/will be different for every image. This may or may not be your intention, I just wanted to give a heads up.